# how to create a voice reminder in android

Tags: android

i am trying to make a voice reminder which take a text to be remembered and on the time the application convert the text to say it in voice i did the code of the reminder and i create another class extend broad cast receiver and did the code to the reminder to fire in time but it run when i make it show a toast but when i write the code of the speech in the receiver to fire in the time set but it gives me " the application force to close" could you please answer me i wrote this in the onreceive but it doesn't work

```
public class ReadyToSpeak extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

  VoiceAlert voicealert= new VoiceAlert();

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context,VoiceAlert.class);
     scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);
     Toast.makeText(context, "onresive", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     //  voicealert.speak();
     voicealert.txs.speak("Hello", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);


  }



}
```

I did the code all over again and didn't work and that is what appear in the logcat

10-27 10:23:06.920: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(127): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-27 10:23:12.671: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(119): No keyboard for id 0
10-27 10:23:12.671: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(119): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-27 10:23:14.081: DEBUG/dalvikvm(127): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2068 objects / 132776 bytes in 77ms
10-27 10:23:33.990: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.anddev.android.speechreminder/.ReminderActivity }
10-27 10:23:34.470: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.speech.tts.engine.CHECK_TTS_DATA cmp=com.svox.pico/.CheckVoiceData }
10-27 10:23:34.710: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity org.anddev.android.speechreminder/.ReminderActivity: 577 ms (total 577 ms)
10-27 10:23:34.720: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(313): No keyboard for id 0
10-27 10:23:34.720: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(313): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-27 10:23:34.780: VERBOSE/TtsService(319): TtsService.onCreate()
10-27 10:23:34.830: VERBOSE/TtsService(319): About to load /system/lib/libttspico.so, applyFilter=true
10-27 10:23:34.910: VERBOSE/TtsService(319): TtsService.setLanguage(eng, USA, )
10-27 10:23:35.120: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Process com.android.alarmclock (pid 170) has died.
10-27 10:23:35.141: INFO/SVOX Pico Engine(319): loaded en-US successfully
10-27 10:23:35.141: INFO/SynthProxy(319): setting speech rate to 100
10-27 10:23:44.870: DEBUG/dalvikvm(296): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1918 objects / 108296 bytes in 159ms
10-27 10:23:49.990: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(114): No keyboard for id 0
10-27 10:23:50.001: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(114): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-27 10:24:18.050: WARN/InputManagerService(58): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44fe6228
10-27 10:24:20.550: DEBUG/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you find a particular response to be a satisfactory answer to your question please click check mark next to the response to accept it.

Comment: Can you please post the full error from the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Taghrid, It looks like you're getting a Stackoverflow error. This indicates that somewhere in your code you have [Infinite recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop#Infinite_recursion). It looks like it's VoiceAlert and ReadyToSpeak functions that keep calling one another. Are you sure the package your using, org.androiddev.android.test is of good quality? Are you using a release version of it?

Comment: Thank you for replay, org.androiddev.android.test is the package which i create to my application and voicealert is an object of a another class VoiceAlert which i did in it the speech code and before i try to register the broadcast the onrecive fire with a toast but didn't fire when i call the speech method

Comment: Do I have to change the package? or do I have to do the application all over again ? and for the loop i need this loop to keep running till the the set time to fire

Comment: The problem is in the package some where. Your problem is with ReadyToSpeak and VoiceAlert. They keep calling one another in an endless cycle.

Comment: I did the could all again and the onrecesive didn't fire on time and added the receiver on the mainfeastfile  but i printed to you the logcat I don't know what to do else